# Beautiful Balloons for Buddha

Tags: traditions

Can someone explain the tradition of releasing balloons with candles inside for Buddha? What is the meaning? Is it a Theravada or a Mahayana tradition? When and why people do it?

Answer (score 1):

Through a search I've found use of releasing lanterns to be common in a few Buddhist areas that host both traditions. In Burma (Myanmar) there is the [Tazaungdaing festival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tazaungdaing_festival), which is celebrated as a national holiday and marks the end of the rainy season. It also marks the end of the Kathina, during which monks are offered new robes and alms.

Most of them sound like lay practice to me. Many countries traditionally celebrate with balloon lanterns.
Is there a specific festival you are referring to?

Comment: A saw that in a movie about thailand and I was wondering the meaning of it, it wasnt the first time I saw it, but I really dont know the meaning

Comment: whoever the grammar police are on here that keep editing all my stuff... i think your attachment to perfection could be a source of suffering... maybe you should chill out! Your obsession with convention and traditional grammar "rules" is quite unnecessary. perhaps you do better to meditate on why youre so worried about it instead of spending that time fixing something that really doesnt "need" to be fixed!

Comment: Yes it happens quite often, but do not worry with it unless someone changes the meaning of what you are saying. I get edited all the time too and I really don't mind, in case they change the meaning of what you are saying or remove it from the original context, you should flag it in a comment

Comment: @ANonimous On all stackexchange websites users can suggest or [make improvements](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to questions and answers. Our goal is to create a high-quality Q&A site. I'm sorry if I've offended you with my edit, my only intention was to make it better readable and provide easy access to additional information. If you disagree with my changes feel free to roll it back (click on 'edit' and then on 'rollback' on your original post). Chances are however that another user will come along and do a similar edit.